# “Insert Ctrl+Alt+Delete” not working on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

"Insert Ctrl+Alt+Delete" option from the Machine menu of the VM doesn't work and neither <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, the VM is a Windows 7 x64 machine exported from a physical machine via "VMware vCenter Converter".

Ideas?

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is required to log in the system, I've tried to change host button and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using RDP to connect to it, you can try using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `End`

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question backwards:

You can turn off the <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> login requirement via the "Local Security Policy" admin applet (Run > `secpol.msg` in Win2003, at least). It's in the "Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options" folder, titled "Interactive Login: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL".

#### So, how to login the first time?

Use Remote Desktop. <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> works fine in that environment (at least, when running with an OS X Host as in my case ... I think it you are running aWindows host you need to use <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> instead).

#### Background:

I've run into a related issue a number of times when trying to change the password of a guest Windows VM, and I've always driven myself nuts trying different keystrokes, none of which work.  In my case it's with an OS X host.

What does work to bring , however, is turning on Remote Desktop on the guest machine and then RDP'ing into it. Then <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> works.

Answer (score -2):

Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work in Virtualbox as if for some reason virtualbox hangs then you could be able to close it from the host windows. Instead for this you have to press the Host button + del to open that menu (by default host button is right Ctrl).

Comment: Host+Del doesn't work either

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl+Alt+Del and Host+Del? Please check if your host is set to Right Control. If that doesn't work you might want to change your host button (In main VB window go to Files -> Preferences -> Input and then change your host button you feel comfortable). Also if nothing works try to go to machine menu (in the host window where Machine is the first menu) and then click "Insert Host+Del (Ctrl+Alt+Del)".

Comment: Did you not see where the questioner said in the first sentence of the question that _that was what xe was doing_?